# Unstable to do resistance measurements due to electric fans

Tags: microcontroller, ac, dc, noise, resistance

I built a small system to monitor wood drying. The idea is to turn on exhaust or circulation fans (230V-AC) based on the absolute humidity and ambient temperature (respectively) of a small drying chamber.

To monitor the progress of the drying, I built a small DC circuit based on voltage dividers to get the resistance of the wood inside; this can be converted to moisture content level in %.

Currently, I am noticing that the measurements are working fine when the fans are off, but that is a very narrow window of time (check plots). Based on this, I am setting the relays of the fans as high or low.

The moisture content measurements are having abrupt jumps and drops which happen when the exhaust or circulation fans are being turned on and off.

[image: Plot of moisture content on the first plot, fans on the last two]

I did not filter mains frequency from the signals yet, I wanted to ask here to get more insight into this problem and hopefully get some nice either signal processing or electric circuit design answers.

Circuit for those who asked:

[image: Circuit]

Comment: @All - Although well-intentioned, the long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued *there* (see link in the comment below). || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here may be deleted without notice. *Keep it in chat now, please!* || Any improvements to the question decided during the chat, should be made via an [edit], not as a comment. When someone has enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. TY

Comment: *Comments have been moved to [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151459/discussion-on-question-by-tino-d-unstable-to-do-resistance-measurements-due-to-e) and discussion should be continued there. Please do not continue the discussion in comments here.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using shielded cables fixed the problem, I will include an image of the results when I collect enough data.

As promised, here is a sample of the data after shielding:

[image]